# Traveling Salesman Problem - Programación competitiva en C++

Tags: c++

Estaba haciendo el problema B de la prueba del Torneo de Programación Argentino de 2016 y no entiendo por qué mi código no produce la respuesta correcta.

El problema en cuestión es una variante del típico Traveling Salesman Problem. Pide recoger como input:

1. Un número señalando cuantos puestos hay en el problema.
2. El numero del puesto que va a usarse como partida
3. El numero del puesto que va a usarse como salida y…
4. … todas las coordenadas cartesianas X e Y de cada uno de los puestos.

El ouput al que hay que llegar es la distancia del recorrido más corto que se puede hacer partiendo de la partida y llegando a la salida pasando una vez por cada uno de los puestos. Si quieren leer el problema tal cual, les dejo el link (pero dice lo mismo).

Este es el código que hice y no se por qué no llega al output correcto (no lo hice con programación dinámica porque primero quería entender bien la lógica del problema, el código no funciona bien con ningún caso, da igual el tamaño del caso):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <matrix>
using namespace std;

struct Punto{
    int x, y;
};

bool soloquedauna(int mask, int dest){
    return (mask & (~(1<<dest))) != 0;
}
    
double recorrido(const matrix<double> &distancias, int mask, int pos, int lugares, int dest){
    double output = 1e9; double respuesta;
    
    if(soloquedauna(mask,dest)){
        return (distancias[pos][dest]);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < lugares; i++){
        if(i==dest) continue;
        if((mask & 1<<i) == 0){
            respuesta= distancias[pos][i]+ recorrido(distancias,mask|(1<<i), i, lugares,dest);
            output = min(output,respuesta);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int lugares, entrada,salida;
    
    cin >> lugares >>entrada >> salida;
    entrada--;salida--;
    
    vector<Punto> puntos(lugares);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < lugares; i++){
        Punto nuevo;
        cin >> nuevo.x >> nuevo.y;
        puntos[i] = nuevo;
    }
    matrix<double> distancias(lugares,lugares);
    for (int i = 0; i < lugares; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < lugares;j++){
            if(i==j) continue;
            distancias[i][j] = sqrt(pow(puntos[i].x-puntos[j].x,2) + pow(puntos[i].y-puntos[j].y,2));
        }
    }
    cout << recorrido(distancias, 1<<entrada, entrada,lugares,salida);

    return 0;
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por leer :)

Comment: Me olvidé del link al problema original xd
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UIm84Fvn7sVJ5X2-8kdBDVPw0MnHMeKF/view?usp=sharing
(es el problema B)

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y arega la info en la pregunta

Comment: ¿La pregunta es sobre el algoritmo o sobre la implementación? Es decir, tal vez el algoritmo sea correcto pero no está bien implementado. O al revés, el algoritmo no es correcto pero está bien implementado.

Comment: El código que aportas no se puede ejcutar, da error `#include <matrix>`. Por favor edita tu pregunta proveyendo un [ejemplo mínimo y reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).